# requesting video from YouTube API to be played in HTML page

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to request videos from YouTube API but I'm only getting the title of the video and its thumbnail. how can i play the video ?

**Note**: I'm using the YouTube documentation in html and JavaScript

I've tried to use item.snippet.player.embedHtml and put it in  but nothing were shown.

**This is my code:**

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttons">
    <label> <input id="query" type="text"/><button id="search-button"   onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>    
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>           
    <script>
     function keyWordsearch(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey('');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                makeRequest();
        });
}
    function makeRequest() {
        var q = $('#query').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 1
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                $('#results').empty()
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
                vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;                 
                vidThumbimg = '<pre><img id="thumb" src="'+vidThumburl+'" alt="No  Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"></pre>';                   

                $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + vidThumbimg +  '</pre>');                      
        })  
    })  
}
  </script> 
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you insert your data into an `img` - that won't play at all.

Answer (score 0):

You insert your data into an `img` - that won't play at all.

Try to use the following `video` snippet for `vidThumbimg`:

```
vidThumburl = item.contentDetails.videoId;

vidThumbimg = '<video>
               <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vidThumburl + '" type="video/ogg">
               <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vidThumburl + '" type="video/mp4">
               </video>'
```

Comment: yes I've tried to do this item.snippet.player.embedHtml and put it in <iframe> tag but it didn't work. @FelixHäberle

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `iFrame`

```
let videoThumbnail = '<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"' +
        'src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + 
        '?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder = "0" ></iframe>';

$('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + videoThumbnail + '</pre>');
```

EDIT:
You must provide your own API key: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emjms/5km2Lg3o/)

Comment: Still nothing is displayed. @emjames

Comment: Did you check the developer console for errors? If you're not using an API key you might have exceeded the limit for unauthenticated usage

Comment: Yes i have checked and i have  my own API key from YouTube.@emjames

Comment: Try the JSFiddle and take notes of any errors that may appear @Al-Hanouf

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try php?

```
$videoID = 'ylLzyHk54Z0';  // change to suit
$ytrequrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails,status,player,topicDetails&id='.$videoID.'&key='.$apikey;

<?php
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // replace with your key
$info= file_get_contents($ytrequrl);
$info= json_decode($info, true);

print("<pre>".print_r($info,true)."</pre>");
?>
```

UPDATE::

A basic example to get you going.

```
    <?php
    $apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // replace with your key
    error_reporting(0);
    if(isset($_GET['video'])){
        $videoID = $_GET['video'];
    }
    $ytrequrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,player&id='.$videoID.'&key='.$apikey;
    $info= file_get_contents($ytrequrl);
    $info= json_decode($info, true);
    $userId =  $info['items']['0']['id'];
    $channel_name =  $info['items']['0']['snippet']['title'];
    $channel_thumbnail = $info['items']['0']['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
    $watch = $info['items']['0']['player']['embedHtml']; 
    ?>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_parent">
    <input name="video" type="text" value="<?php echo $videoID ?>" size="30">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    <?php echo $userId ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo $channel_name ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo $channel_thumbnail ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo $watch ?>
    <br />
    </body>
```

>

Comment: Thats cool! i'm not good in php. can you please tell me how can i make a search box so that the user can enter any text to search not an ID.

Comment: Change to `$videoID = $_GET['video'];`  . Then send a post to self. url will then look like this www.yoursite.com/?video=ylLzyHk54Z0

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. But can i search by caption of the video instead of ID?@tempus

Comment: @Al-Hanouf accept answer if it is correct. Only polite to do so. As for captions, you can search if a video has or not. Then you can get caption info . Read this for more https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list